# Implementation of mqtt protocol using mosquitto APIs

Tags: c, ubuntu, mqtt, mosquitto

I am trying to send packets based on mqtt protocol using mosquitto APIs. I was able to send message directly from the command line using commands `mosquitto_pub -t "topic/path" -m "message payload" -h "<IP address>" -q 1 -r` and `mosquitto_sub -t "topic/path"` for publisher and subscriber respectively.

Now, once I am writing my own program in C using mosquitto APIs to implement the same, I am getting undefined reference to `mosquitto_loop_forever` error. Interestingly, it occurs in later versions of ubuntu 12.04. I installed the required libs but still I am facing this issue.

Any suggestions you could make would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your test code (and the command you used to compile/link) it so we can see if there is anything wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely cause for this is that you are using an old version of libmosquitto - the version in the ubuntu repositories is out of date by quite a long way.

You should use the following commands to get access to the latest version through the mosquitto PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mosquitto-dev/mosquitto-ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Or possibly:

```
sudo apt-get install libmosquitto-dev
```